# Get Controller Object and Controller Strong Params in Application Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, controller, strong-parameters, applicationcontroller

Hello people. 
 I'm creating a log process in my Rails 5 application, inside the `application controller`. I'm creating there because I want to call the log process inside many controllers with a `before_save` property. The log will save the changes that user performs in the `form` on `edit view template`. The problem is that I can't get the `<ObjectController:>` inside `application controller`. I've already got the `instance variable` from the controller, but I need the `ObjectController` too, because I have to get the `strong parameters` from controller object. The `strong parameters` holds all data that user inserted on input fields.

This is what I've done already:

app/controllers/application controller

```
def log
    @controlr = instance_variable_get("@#{controller_name.singularize}") #get the edited object
    attribs = @controlr.attribute_names #get object table column names
    edited_data = controlr_params #stuck here!
    ctrlr = @controlr.attributes #retrive object data from db
    ...
    ##compare the edited_data with the actual data from db and check if something was changed
end
```

So, I need to obtain the Controller Object to access the strong parameters in order to compare if user edited any data. I'm not sure if this is the best way/practice to do this. If there is a better way, I'd like to know. But I need to call this process in a great number of controllers that require a data log.
Thanks for you time and sorry any bad english..

Answer (score 0):

If `params` method won't help you to achieve your goal (but it's worth to try) you can always access current instance of controller object by calling **`self`** in context of any instance method or action.

To test you can put [`byebug`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) in any action, call that action in browser with additional parameters and type `self` in console.

For example, in controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    byebug
  end
end
```

in browser:

> localhost:3000/?some_param=1234&another_param=testing

There will be a lot of useful stuff in there, like `self.instance_variables` => `[.... :@_request, ... :@_params]`.

Also `request` method contain all info about current request including parameters.

Hope that'll help.

Comment: Thanks @Vladv for the answer. Using "self" inside application controller is now returning me the Controller Object <EntitiesController:0x000...>. But now, I have to get the "entity_params" private method inside "entities_controller". When I try to print this method, it throws the error "param is missing or the value is empty: Entities". If I define a new method to return the private method, it throws "private method `testeParams' called for #<EntidadesController:0x0000561955ce7b28>" Any idea how can/should I get these parameters?